# How to convert from boost::multiprecision::cpp_int to cpp_dec_float<0> (rather than to cpp_dec_float_50, etc.)?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, multiprecision

As is made clear in the [Boost Multiprecision library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/conversions.html) documentation, it is straightforward to convert from a `boost::multiprecision::cpp_int` to a `boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float`:

```
// Some interconversions between number types are completely generic,
// and are always available, albeit the conversions are always explicit:

cpp_int cppi(2);
cpp_dec_float_50 df(cppi);    // OK, int to float // <-- But fails with cpp_dec_float<0>!
```

The ability to convert from a `cpp_int` to a fixed-width floating-point type (i.e., a `cpp_dec_float_50`) gives one hope that it might be possible to convert from a `cpp_int` to an *arbitrary-width* floating-point type in the library - i.e., a `cpp_dec_float<0>`.  However, this doesn't work; the conversion fails for me in Visual Studio 2013, as the following simple example program demonstrates:

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/number.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_dec_float.hpp>

int main()
{
    boost::multiprecision::cpp_int n{ 0 };
    boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float<0> f{ n }; // Compile error in MSVC 2013
}
```

It *does* succeed to convert to `cpp_dec_float_50`, as expected, but as noted, I am hoping to convert to an arbitrary precision floating point type: `cpp_dec_float<0>`.

The error appear in the following snippet of code from the internal Boost Multiprecision code, in the file `<boost/multiprecision/detail/default_ops.hpp>`:

```
template <class R, class T>
inline bool check_in_range(const T& t)
{
   // Can t fit in an R?
   if(std::numeric_limits<R>::is_specialized && std::numeric_limits<R>::is_bounded
      && (t > (std::numeric_limits<R>::max)()))
      return true;
   return false;
}
```

The error message is:

> error C2784:
>   'enable_if::result_type,detail::expression::result_type>,bool>::type
>   boost::multiprecision::operator >(const
>   boost::multiprecision::detail::expression
>   &,const
>   boost::multiprecision::detail::expression &)' :
>   could not deduce template argument for 'const
>   boost::multiprecision::detail::expression &'
>   from 'const next_type'

Might it be possible to convert a `boost::multiprecision::cpp_int` to a `boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float<0>` (rather than converting to a floating-point type with a fixed decimal precision, as in `cpp_dec_float_50`)?

(Note that in my program, only one instance of the floating-point number is instantiated at any time, and it is updated infrequently, so I am fine with having this one instance take up lots of memory and take a long time to support really huge numbers.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I don't have much experience with Boost Multiprecision, but it seems to me that the template class `cpp_dec_float<>` is what they call a *backend*, and you need to wrap it in a `number<>` adaptor in order to use it as an arithmetic type.

Here's my take on it: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d445521ea60cb4cb)**

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/number.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_dec_float.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace mp = boost::multiprecision;

int main()
{
    using Int = mp::cpp_int;

    // let's think of a nice large number
    Int n = 1;
    for (Int f = 42; f>0; --f)
        n *= f;

    std::cout << n << "\n\n"; // print it for vanity 

    // let's convert it to cpp_dec_float
    // and... do something with it
    using Dec = mp::number<mp::cpp_dec_float<0> >;
    std::cout << n.convert_to<Dec>();
}
```

Output:

```
1405006117752879898543142606244511569936384000000000

1.40501e+51
```

If `convert_to<>` is allowed, then the *explicit conversion constructor* will also work, I expect:

```
Dec decfloat(n);
```

Comment: Great!  I'll try this out probably tomorrow and let you know if it works for me as well.

Comment: @Gracchus It doesn't truncate? The precision is completely full fidelity. Just the screen representation isn't, by default. Why? Well, because having numbers that run on for pages is rarely useful. People have a tough time reading number of >30 digits... So, use Boost Serialization for that if you need full precision serialization?

Comment: @Gracchus I was just finishing the answer on the [rounding question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23033117/85371). I was a little short on time earlier and got confused with the library :/ Let me have a look shortly regarding the presentation question.