# Efficient computation of n choose k in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, performance

I have some performance sensitive code on a Node.js server that needs to count combinations. From [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15302448/4019986), I used this simple recursive function for computing n choose k:

```
function choose(n, k) {
    if (k === 0) return 1;
    return (n * choose(n-1, k-1)) / k;
}
```

Then since we all know iteration is almost always faster than recursion, I wrote this function based on the [multiplicative formula](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15302394/4019986):

```
function choosei(n,k){
    var result = 1;
    for(var i=1; i <= k; i++){
        result *= (n+1-i)/i;
    }
    return result;
}
```

I ran a few [benchmarks](https://github.com/bestiejs/benchmark.js/) on my machine. Here are the results of just one of them:

```
Recursive x 178,836 ops/sec ±7.03% (60 runs sampled)
Iterative x 550,284 ops/sec ±5.10% (51 runs sampled)
Fastest is Iterative
```

The results consistently showed that the iterative method is indeed about 3 to 4 times faster than the recursive method in Node.js (at least on my machine).

This is *probably* fast enough for my needs, but **is there any way to make it faster**? My code has to call this function very frequently, sometimes with fairly large values of `n` and `k`, so the faster the better.

## EDIT

After running a few more tests with le_m's and Mike's solutions, it turns out that while both are significantly faster than the iterative method I proposed, Mike's method using Pascal's triangle appears to be slightly faster than le_m's log table method.

```
Recursive x 189,036 ops/sec ±8.83% (58 runs sampled)
Iterative x 538,655 ops/sec ±6.08% (51 runs sampled)
LogLUT x 14,048,513 ops/sec ±9.03% (50 runs sampled)
PascalsLUT x 26,538,429 ops/sec ±5.83% (62 runs sampled)
Fastest is PascalsLUT
```

The logarithmic look up method has been around 26-28 times faster than the iterative method in my tests, and the method using Pascal's triangle has been about 1.3 to 1.8 times faster than the logarithmic look up method.

Note that I followed le_m's suggestion of pre-computing the logarithms with higher precision using [mathjs](http://mathjs.org/index.html), then converted them back to regular JavaScript `Number`s (which are always [double-precision 64 bit floats](http://www.2ality.com/2012/04/number-encoding.html)).

Comment: Memoization can be fastest choice, if space is not your concern.

Comment: From the comment on the answer you linked and from the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Factorial_formula): `if (k > n/2) return choose(n, n-k);` - which will help when both `n` and `k` are large, but the additional branch might slow down overall execution.

Comment: @Godfather @NanoWizard and If you dont have the space to momoize the choosei results, you can get good performance increases by momoizing the factorials. You can even have a dynamic programming technique to compute the factorial `fact(n) = max_known_fact_value(n) * [i for evey int for max_known_fact_int(n) to n]` that would save significant time

Comment: yeah @gbtimmon that will be great!

Comment: build pascal's triangle. It is much faster.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Why build the triangle when you just need the (log)-factorials for an O(1) solution?

Comment: @le_m you might have misunderstood the instruction: build the triangle, save the LUT, use that LUT. If you need to, at any point during the runtime of your application, actually *compute* binomial terms, you are wasting time. Those values are constants that can simply be included and consulted in O(1).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I don't think I misunderstood: A pascal triangle LUT has an O(n²) space requirement which might be problematic.

Comment: Not for practical purposes though. Using UINT16, you can store the LUT up to n=19 in 380 bytes + array overhead. UINT32 allows for up to n=35 in a fraction over 2kb. UINT64 allows up to n=68 and now we've properly shot beyond "do you honestly believe you need binomial coefficients this high?" values at a fraction over 18kb. These are mallocs that no one in their right mind would care about if they already committed to doing binomial computation. Especially in Node.js, where these LUTs are insignificant compared to even base Node's memory footprint.

Comment: just noticed that last edit: remember that the largest true _integer_ in JS is only 2^53. After that, `(v - (v + n))` is no longer guaranteed to be `n`. For instance: `a = 2**53; b = 2**53 + 1; b - a` is zero in JS, not 1.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Never compute factorials, they grow too quickly. Instead compute the result you want. In this case, you want the binomial numbers, which have an incredibly simple geometric construction: you can build [pascal's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle), as you need it, and do it using plain arithmetic.

Start with [1] and [1,1]. The next row has [1] at the start, [1+1] in the middle, and [1] at the end: [1,2,1]. Next row: [1] at the start, the sum of the first two terms in spot 2, the sum of the next two terms in spot three, and [1] at the end: [1,3,3,1]. Next row: [1], then 1+3=4, then 3+3=6, then 3+1=4, then [1] at the end, and so on and so on. As you can see, no factorials, logarithms, or even multiplications: just super fast addition with clean integer numbers. So simple, you can build a massive lookup table by hand.

And you should.

Never compute in code what you can compute by hand and just include as constants for immediate lookup; in this case, writing out the table for up to something around n=20 is absolutely trivial, and you can then just use that as your "starting LUT" and probably never even access the high rows.

But, if you do need them, or more, then because you can't build an infinite lookup table you compromise: you start with a pre-specified LUT, and a function that can "fill it up" to some term you need that's not in it yet:

```
// step 1: a basic LUT with a few steps of Pascal's triangle
const binomials = [
  [1],
  [1,1],
  [1,2,1],
  [1,3,3,1],
  [1,4,6,4,1],
  [1,5,10,10,5,1],
  [1,6,15,20,15,6,1],
  [1,7,21,35,35,21,7,1],
  [1,8,28,56,70,56,28,8,1],
  //  ...
];

// step 2: a function that builds out the LUT if it needs to.
module.exports = function binomial(n,k) {
  while(n >= binomials.length) {
    let s = binomials.length;
    let nextRow = [];
    nextRow[0] = 1;
    for(let i=1, prev=s-1; i<s; i++) {
      nextRow[i] = binomials[prev][i-1] + binomials[prev][i];
    }
    nextRow[s] = 1;
    binomials.push(nextRow);
  }
  return binomials[n][k];
};
```

Since this is an array of ints, the memory footprint is tiny. For a lot of work involving binomials, we realistically don't even need more than two bytes per integer, making this a *minuscule* lookup table: we don't need more than 2 bytes until you need binomials higher than n=19, and the full lookup table up to n=19 takes up a measly 380 bytes. This is nothing compared to the rest of your program. Even if we allow for 32 bit ints, we can get up to n=35 in a mere 2380 bytes.

So the lookup is fast: either O(constant) for previously computed values, (n*(n+1))/2 steps if we have no LUT at all (in big O notation, that would be O(n²), but big O notation is almost never the right complexity measure), and somewhere in between for terms we need that aren't in the LUT yet. Run some benchmarks for your application, which will tell you how big your initial LUT should be, simply hard code that (seriously. these are constants, they're are *exactly* the kind of values that *should* be hard coded), and keep the generator around just in case.

However, do remember that you're in JavaScript land, and you are constrained by the JavaScript numerical type: [integers only go up to 2^53](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_8.5), beyond that the integer property (every `n` has a distinct `m=n+1` such that `m-n=1`) is not guaranteed. This should hardly ever be a problem, though: once we hit that limit, we're dealing with binomial coefficients that you should never even be using.

Comment: There is an error in the last row of the lut array. For anyone copy pasting, replace 54 with 56 or just remove that line. Lazy mans proof: https://www.google.com/search?q=8+choose+3

Comment: I didn't realize you would see the comment, but good you fixed it.

Comment: For those who like a bit of JS madness: this is the part after `let s = ...` in the while loop, as a one-liner: `binomials.push(new Array(s+1).fill(0).map((_, i) => i == 0 || i == s ? 1 : binomials[s-1][i-1] + binomials[s-1][i]));`

Comment: @sigalor no need for `new Array(s+1).fill(0).map()`, just use modern JS: `[...Array(s+1)].map()`. If you're trying to micro-optimize in a way that doesn't actually execute any faster anyway =)

Comment: And as a several-years-later comment, we now have Uint8Array and Uint16Array, which *are* sized arrays, so you can now _force_ your memory footprint using `new Uint8Array(rowsize)` or the (completely overkill) `new Uint16Array(rowsize)`

Comment: One need only calculate half the array because binomial(n,m)=binomial(n,n-m). You need to add a couple of code lines to check if the row is even or odd (or else add two rows at a time), but it runs twice as fast.

Comment: does it though? Because it's already just "addition with lookup", so your improvement might not actually be appreciably faster. That said, if you can show it runs notably faster, happy to add that to the post.

Answer (score 15):

The following algorithm has a run-time complexity of **O(1)** given a linear look-up table of log-factorials with space-complexity **O(n)**.

Limiting **n** and **k** to the range [0, 1000] makes sense since `binomial(1000, 500)` is already dangerously close to `Number.MAX_VALUE`. We would thus need a look-up table of size 1000.

On a modern JavaScript engine, a compact array of n numbers has a size of n * 8 bytes. A full look-up table would thus require 8 kilobytes of memory. If we limit our input to the range [0, 100], the table would only occupy 800 bytes.

```js
var logf = [0, 0, 0.6931471805599453, 1.791759469228055, 3.1780538303479458, 4.787491742782046, 6.579251212010101, 8.525161361065415, 10.60460290274525, 12.801827480081469, 15.104412573075516, 17.502307845873887, 19.987214495661885, 22.552163853123425, 25.19122118273868, 27.89927138384089, 30.671860106080672, 33.50507345013689, 36.39544520803305, 39.339884187199495, 42.335616460753485, 45.38013889847691, 48.47118135183523, 51.60667556776438, 54.78472939811232, 58.00360522298052, 61.261701761002, 64.55753862700634, 67.88974313718154, 71.25703896716801, 74.65823634883016, 78.0922235533153, 81.55795945611504, 85.05446701758152, 88.58082754219768, 92.1361756036871, 95.7196945421432, 99.33061245478743, 102.96819861451381, 106.63176026064346, 110.32063971475739, 114.0342117814617, 117.77188139974507, 121.53308151543864, 125.3172711493569, 129.12393363912722, 132.95257503561632, 136.80272263732635, 140.67392364823425, 144.5657439463449, 148.47776695177302, 152.40959258449735, 156.3608363030788, 160.3311282166309, 164.32011226319517, 168.32744544842765,  172.3527971391628, 176.39584840699735, 180.45629141754378, 184.53382886144948, 188.6281734236716, 192.7390472878449, 196.86618167289, 201.00931639928152, 205.1681994826412, 209.34258675253685, 213.53224149456327, 217.73693411395422, 221.95644181913033, 226.1905483237276, 230.43904356577696, 234.70172344281826, 238.97838956183432, 243.2688490029827, 247.57291409618688, 251.8904022097232, 256.22113555000954, 260.5649409718632, 264.9216497985528, 269.2910976510198, 273.6731242856937, 278.0675734403661, 282.4742926876304, 286.893133295427, 291.3239500942703, 295.76660135076065, 300.22094864701415, 304.6868567656687, 309.1641935801469, 313.65282994987905, 318.1526396202093, 322.66349912672615, 327.1852877037752, 331.7178871969285, 336.26118197919845, 340.815058870799, 345.37940706226686, 349.95411804077025, 354.5390855194408, 359.1342053695754, 363.73937555556347];

function binomial(n, k) {
    return Math.exp(logf[n] - logf[n-k] - logf[k]);
}

console.log(binomial(5, 3));
```

**Explanation**

Starting with the original iterative algorithm, we first replace the product with a sum of logarithms:

```
function binomial(n, k) {
    var logresult = 0;
    for (var i = 1; i <= k; i++) {
        logresult += Math.log(n + 1 - i) - Math.log(i);
    }
    return Math.exp(logresult);
}
```

Our loop now sums over k terms. If we rearrange the sum, we can easily see that we sum over consecutive logarithms `log(1) + log(2) + ... + log(k)` etc. which we can replace by a `sum_of_logs(k)` which is actually identical to `log(k!)`. Precomputing these values and storing them in our lookup-table `logf` then leads to the above one-liner algorithm.

**Computing the look-up table:**

I recommend precomputing the lookup-table with higher precision and converting the resulting elements to 64-bit floats. If you do not need that little bit of additional precision or want to run this code on the client side, use this:

```
var size = 1000, logf = new Array(size);
logf[0] = 0;
for (var i = 1; i <= size; ++i) logf[i] = logf[i-1] + Math.log(i);
```

**Numerical precision:**

By using log-factorials, we avoid precision problems inherent to storing raw factorials.

We could even use [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) for `log(n!)` instead of a lookup-table and still get 12 significant figures for above computation in both run-time and space complexity **O(1)**:

```js
function logf(n) {
    return n === 0 ? 0 : (n + .5) * Math.log(n) - n + 0.9189385332046728 + 0.08333333333333333 / n - 0.002777777777777778 * Math.pow(n, -3);
}

function binomial(n , k) {
    return Math.exp(logf(n) - logf(n - k) - logf(k));
}

console.log(binomial(1000, 500)); // 2.7028824094539536e+299
```

Comment: Arithmetic operations are performed on 64-bit floating point values, thus you would need to e. g. format the result before printing by truncating insignificant fractional digits.

Comment: I think this is a typo - `log(1) + log(2) + ... + log(k)` should be `log(k!)` instead of `log(n!)`.

Answer (score -1):

Using Pascal's triangle is a fast method for calculating n choose k.

The fastest method I know of would be to make use of the results from "[On the Complexity of Calculating Factorials](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0196677485900069)". Just calculate all 3 factorials, then perform the two division operations, each with [complexity M(n logn)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations).

Comment: There is no "just" in "just calculate a factorial": calculating `n` factorial requires `n-1` multiplications, something which cpus are _incredibly_ bad at compared to addition. The paper you're citing talks about complexity in terms of `n` only, not in terms of cpu operations, which is ostensibly what the question was about. It asked for efficient computation.