# How do I write a program that calculates n/2 by selecting a specific number of elements in a set. In python

Tags: python

For example, if the set is `{0, 1, 2, 3}`, then the different ways to choose two elements is: `{0,1}, {0,2}, {0,3}, {1,2}, {1,3}, {2,3}`. So `!4$ = 6`.

Comment: What is n and why do you divide it by 2?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficient computation of n choose k in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37679987/efficient-computation-of-n-choose-k-in-node-js)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `itertools.combinations`

```
import itertools
elts = {1, 2, 3, 4}
result = [i for i in  itertools.combinations(elts, 2)]
print (result) #[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]
```