# react-konva performace issue when render 4000+ n order bezier curve shape

Tags: performance, bezier, react-konva

Now i need to render thousands of n order bezer curve shape in my draggable stage, using react-konva.It is working in first rendering.But when i drag the stage, fps is going to unstable.There is  a demo. [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/konva-bezier-mdpsf5?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js%3A50%2C52)

I had try some optimization tips, such as cache bezier array caculation, optimize strokes, disable perfect drawing.It seems better, but still not have a smooth animation when i drag it.

Comment: Looking at your BezierMaker: _never_ use factorials because _you don't want factorials_. You want binomial coefficients, which you don't even need to compute just use a [Pascal's Triangle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37716142/740553) lookup table. Factorials are for proofs, not for implementations.

Comment: thanks.i forgot i asked on the stackoverflow.i need to figure out how the pascal's triangle is working

Answer (score 0):

If possible, you should think about caching. It will boost performance a lot:

```js
const layerRef = React.useRef();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    layerRef.current.cache({
      width: 200,
      height: 200,
    });
  }, []);

<Layer ref={layerRef}>
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/konva-bezier-forked-j298rj?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js%3A47%2C7-47%2C29

Comment: it Improved a lot of performance!!! i will try caching in my project