# How can I make my recursvie n choose k function work with big numbers in Python?

Tags: python, recursion

The title says it all, my function isn't working with big numbers. For example (1000 C 800) would crash it.

```
def choose(n, k):
    if n == k:
        return 1
    elif k == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return choose(n-1, k) + choose(n-1, k-1)
```

Comment: Any recursive solution can be made an iterative method by using a data-structure to store previous results. As for the answer to your question this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301885/calculate-value-of-n-choose-k

Comment: Do not use recursion, neither iteration.  A closed form solution exists.

Answer (score 0):

```
def choose(n, k):
  dp = [[0 for x in xrange(k+1)] for x in xrange(n+1)]

  for i in xrange(n+1):
    for j in xrange(k+1):
      if j > i:
        continue
      if j == 0:
        dp[i][j] = 1
      elif j == i:
        dp[i][j] = 1
      else:
        dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j-1] + dp[i-1][j]

  return dp[n][k]
```

You could use dynamic programming to avoid calculating the same subproblems over and over again. It comes at the cost of some space.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid repeated recalculation of the same sub result, you could use a bottom-up, iterative solution, building a row of [Pascal's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle), and then the next one from it, ...etc:

```
def choose(n, k):
    lst = [1] * (n+1)
    for j in range(1, n):
        for i in range(j, 0, -1):
            lst[i] += lst[i-1]
    return lst[k]

print(choose(1000, 800))
```

> 661715556065930365627163346132458831897321703017638669364788134708891795956726411057801285583913163781806953211915554723373931451847059830252175887712457307547649354135460619296383882957897161889636280577155889117185

This is just to show how to make the approach more efficient, but there are of course [several more efficient ways to calculate C(n,k)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025162/statistics-combinations-in-python).

Answer (score 0):

You can make the recursive approach perform a lot *better* by dividing through factors:

```
def choose(n, k):
    if k == 0:
        return 1
    return n * choose(n-1, k-1) // k
```

This uses the recurrence relation:

[image: 1]

This approach will instantly compute 1000 C 800 without blowing the recursion stack.  But, the underlying problem is still there - it's just postponed to much larger numbers.  You may prefer to use one of the various closed-form solutions instead, for example:

```
from math import factorial

def choose(n, k):
    if n < k:
        n = k - n
    return factorial(n) // (factorial(k) * factorial(n-k))
```