# How to get all combination between N objects with K values C#

Tags: c#, combinations, permutation, cartesian-product

I'm looking for an algorithm that can solve my issue.
I'm working on a project which deals with products and their attributes.
Here I have a product that has N number of options and the options each have K number of values. For example, a Laptop has color, memory, and display options. Each of these has different values.
What I need is to create multiple product variations from this single product. This means I need a variation for each possible combination between the options I have. See the image for a better explanation. I'm working with C#. [image: Diagram of all product variations]

Keep in mind that this needs to be dynamic, as for each product I may have different amounts of oprion and different amount of otion values.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: So you want the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of the options of each items

Comment: Possibly related: [Algorithm for Calculating Binomial Coefficient](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12983731).  [See also](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my understanding of your description, I would say that a product may be represented by the following class:

```csharp
public class Product
{
    public List<Option> Options { get; set; }
    
    public List<List<string>> GetAllCombinations()
    {
        // TODO
    }
}

public class Option
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    public List<string> Values { get; set; }
}
```

Your question is then:

> What needs to happen inside `GetAllCombinations()` to give you the expected result?

What size of `N` and `K` are we talking about? If they do not get much larger than in your example scenario, the following implementation is a possible approach:

```csharp
public List<List<string>> GetAllCombinations()
{
    if (Options == null || !Options.Any())
    {
        return new();
    }
    
    var combinations = new List<List<string>> { new() };
    
    foreach (var option in Options)
    {
        combinations = combinations
            .SelectMany(combination => option.Values
                .Select(optionValue => new List<string>(combination) { optionValue }))
            .ToList();
    }
    
    return combinations;
}
```

What happens inside the `.SelectMany()` is basically:

> For each existing combination, create one new combination per option value that consists of the existing combination *and* the option value.

**Notice that `combinations` is created as *a list containing an empty list*.** Starting off with an empty list inside the outer list (rather than the outer list being empty) is key here, seeing as *each new combination set is always created based on the existing content of `combinations`*; i.e. if `combinations` is an empty list to begin with, it will simply never be populated.

The population of `combinations` is perhaps easier to visualize with a detailed example. Let us create a product similar to the one you have described in your question post and generate all combinations as follows:

```csharp
Product product = new()
{
    Options = new()
    {
        new() { Name = "Color", Values = new() { "Blue", "Yellow", "Green" } },
        new() { Name = "Memory", Values = new() { " 32 GB", " 64 GB", "128 GB" } },
        new() { Name = "Display", Values = new() { " HD", "FHD", "UHD" } },
    }
};

var combinations = product.GetAllCombinations();
```

The content of `combinations` inside `GetAllCombinations()` will be the following:

`combinations` after creation:

```csharp
{
    { } // empty list
}
```

`combinations` after first iteration of the `foreach` loop:

```csharp
{
    { "Blue"   },
    { "Yellow" },
    { "Green"  }
}
```

`combinations` after second iteration of the `foreach` loop:

```csharp
{
    { "Blue",      " 32 GB" },
    { "Blue",      " 64 GB" },
    { "Blue",      "128 GB" },
    { "Yellow",    " 32 GB" },
    { "Yellow",    " 64 GB" },
    { "Yellow",    "128 GB" },
    { "Green",     " 32 GB" },
    { "Green",     " 64 GB" },
    { "Green",     "128 GB" },
}
```

`combinations` after third (last) iteration of the `foreach` loop:

```csharp
{
    { "Blue",      " 32 GB",    " HD" },
    { "Blue",      " 32 GB",    "FHD" },
    { "Blue",      " 32 GB",    "UHD" },
    { "Blue",      " 64 GB",    " HD" },
    { "Blue",      " 64 GB",    "FHD" },
    { "Blue",      " 64 GB",    "UHD" },
    { "Blue",      "128 GB",    " HD" },
    { "Blue",      "128 GB",    "FHD" },
    { "Blue",      "128 GB",    "UHD" },
    { "Yellow",    " 32 GB",    " HD" },
    { "Yellow",    " 32 GB",    "FHD" },
    { "Yellow",    " 32 GB",    "UHD" },
    { "Yellow",    " 64 GB",    " HD" },
    { "Yellow",    " 64 GB",    "FHD" },
    { "Yellow",    " 64 GB",    "UHD" },
    { "Yellow",    "128 GB",    " HD" },
    { "Yellow",    "128 GB",    "FHD" },
    { "Yellow",    "128 GB",    "UHD" },
    { "Green",     " 32 GB",    " HD" },
    { "Green",     " 32 GB",    "FHD" },
    { "Green",     " 32 GB",    "UHD" },
    { "Green",     " 64 GB",    " HD" },
    { "Green",     " 64 GB",    "FHD" },
    { "Green",     " 64 GB",    "UHD" },
    { "Green",     "128 GB",    " HD" },
    { "Green",     "128 GB",    "FHD" },
    { "Green",     "128 GB",    "UHD" }
}
```

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/w5kRh5).