# How to implement N choose R?

Tags: c++

I just wrote this code :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

unsigned long long int choose(unsigned long long int k, unsigned long long int n)
{
    if (k==n or k==0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return (choose(n-1,k-1)+choose(n-1,k));
    }
}

int main(){
    cout << choose(3, 6);
}
```

but I got Run-Time Error, I think my problem is in my variables, I did debugging but I couldn't find the answer, why I got run time error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Binomial coefficient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256188/binomial-coefficient)

Comment: The "choose" function is the binomial coefficient.

Comment: @anthony-arnold that question doesn't come close as a dupe.

Comment: i dont want to copy anothers code

Comment: @anthony-arnold if u have my answer help me,else don't bother me

Comment: OK, I won't bother you any more.

Answer (score 2):

Since your variables are unsigned, substracting `1` from them when they're already `0` will make them roll over to the max value.

When `n` reaches `0` and you then call `choose(n-1,k)`, this'll happen and that's the source of the issue (stackoverflow).

Comment: How Can i fix it?i think i have to insert some IF

Comment: @user3700182 `or n == 0`?

Comment: do yo mean  ::  if(k==n or k==0 or n==0)
??

Comment: @user3700182 do you think that makes sense?

Comment: @user3700182 some other piece of advice - unless this is your coding convention, use the more idiomatic `||` instead of `or`.